# How To Load HTML5 Video Element In Ionic 2

Tags: html, angular, css, ionic2, ionic3

I have been trying to display a list of videos from my server and im facing some difficulties.
This is how the app looks like.

[image]

This is my html code

```
<ion-list>
      <button ion-item *ngFor="let video of recentVideos">
        <ion-thumbnail item-left (click)="openVideo(video)">
          <video>
            <source [src]="video.fileUrl" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <div (click)="openVideo(video)">
          <h2>{{ video.title }}</h2>
          <p>{{ video.description }}</p>
        </div>
        <button ion-button clear item-right icon-only (click)="showPopoverMenu($event, video)">
          <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </button>
    </ion-list>
```

I dont understand why its displaying like that. The video plays fine, am using the ionic native streaming media plugin.
Can anybody see why the video displays as such ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `button` and use `ion-item` as shown below.

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let video of recentVideos">
        <ion-thumbnail item-left (click)="openVideo(video)">
          <video>
            <source [src]="video.fileUrl" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <div (click)="openVideo(video)">
          <h2>{{ video.title }}</h2>
          <p>{{ video.description }}</p>
        </div>
        <button ion-button clear item-right icon-only (click)="showPopoverMenu($event, video)">
          <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: Changing from button to ion-item didn't work same problem exists